# change shortcut in scite dialog

Tags: scite

does anyone know how to change alt-a (replace all) in scite's replace dialog to another shortcut? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can change one of ScITE's profile files by selecting from the Options menu. I usually change the User-level profile but the Global file is useful for seeing a more exhaustive list of settings.

Note 1: If you are the only user, you could change the Global settings but the User-level is just fine. One advantage to changing the User file, at lease in my case, is that User-level file (named .SciTEUser.properties) is saved in my /home/user_name directory -- I'm using Linux -- so it's included in my data backups.

Note 2: I found that altering ScITE settings is like shopping at Costco. You go in with a $30 shopping list in mind and leave $300 later. The number of things  you can customize in ScITE is spectacular. It's the first time I have had an editor that feels tailor-made.

The ScITE website provides the documentation. Specifically, you'll want to look for "user.shortcuts" in [this link](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html). That section provides a [link](http://www.scintilla.org/CommandValues.html) to all of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

2 methods:
 1. Use ResourceHacker and the uncompressed verion of SciTE.
You can get it from http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/
Open SciTE.exe with it, go to dialogs/400/1033.
Change the line that starts with

```
CONTROL "Replace &All"
```

Then recompile script.
 2. recompile the source code...
Unzip the scite source and look for win32\SciTERes.rc
Roundabout line 400 you find the following line:

```
PUSHBUTTON      "Replace &All",IDREPLACEALL,190,41,90,14
```

You can move the ampersand to a different position to change the shortcut key.
Then recompile SciTE